# How to refresh skeletons for Python plugin in IntelliJ?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, intellij-python

I know there is a way to force skeletons refreshment in PyCharm:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000738804-How-to-update-skeletons-remote-interpreter

But I can't find how to do the same in Python plugin in IntelliJ. Can someone please kindly help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in IDEA. Please follow the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21392